# Me da error urls.py al importa el archivo views

Tags: python

Al poner en el archivo urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Aloha_Wind.views import saludo


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('fecha/', saludo ),
    
    
]
```

Me da erro from Aloha_Wind.veiws import saludo

Este es mi archivo veiws.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def saludo (request):
    return HttpResponse(' Este es la primera vista')
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Aloha_Wind.views me lo marca como error

Comment: from Aloha_Wind.views import saludo

Comment: Import "Aloha_Wind.views" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Comment: Este es error que me sale

Answer (score 0):

Y encontrado el error yo estaba poniendo from Aloha_Wind.views import saludo y la soluciones: from views import saludo.

Muchas gracias a todos